# Android: missing features in CMake vs ndk-build

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I'm migrating from ndk-build to CMake (it better integrates with Android Studio, and would enable us to have a single CMakeLists.txt for all platforms).

Unfortunately, our projects use some features of Android.mk that I'm not being able to replicate with CMake. More specifically:

- **TARGET_ARCH**: we use this to include different pre-compiled binaries. How can I find the target arch with CMake?
- **LOCAL_ARM_MODE**: is this even available in CMake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

When using Gradle, CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI is not set! Use CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH or ANDROID_ABI.

**ORIGINAL:**

After a bit more of Google, I've found the answer here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android-with-the-ndk

- CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI or CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH are similar to the ndk-build TARGET_ARCH.
- CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE allows setting the ARM mode (setting it to ON targets 32-bit ARM processors, while to OFF targets 16-bit Thumb processors).

Comment: `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE` is a CMake 3.7 (or higher) feature. Android Studio (2.3.3) uses CMake 3.6. Add `-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm` to `android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.arguments` instead.